# What does "as busy as it gets" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context, ambiguity, phrase-usage

What does "as busy as it gets mean? For instance, 6 PM: Usually as busy as it gets (about a sinagogue). Or the photo below is called "As busy as it gets"[image]

Comment: Why is the same question about "as good as it gets" valid, but mine isn't?